# Tkinter button widget can not locate image, err image doesn't exist

Tags: python, tkinter

When trying to place an image in a button, I get an error "_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist". The image does exist though because I used it on another button and it works there.
When I try to use the image again on a second button that's when the error occurs.

I have tried removing the image and the button works. Tried using the image on anther button and it works for one button only.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Tk, PhotoImage


class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    style = ttk.Style(root)
    style.theme_use('clam')

    root2 = Tk()
    style = ttk.Style(root2)
    style.theme_use('alt')

    root3 = Tk()
    style = ttk.Style(root3)
    style.theme_use('classic')

    root4 = Window()
    style = ttk.Style(root4)
    style.theme_use('default')

    icon = PhotoImage(file='test.gif')
    # This line works, the image appears on the button.
    ttk.Button(root, image=icon, compound='left', text="Quit", command=root.destroy).pack()

    # This line works with out the image.
    ttk.Button(root2, compound='left', text="Quit", command=root2.destroy).pack()

    # This line does not work with an image.
    # if the line below is un-commented the code does not work, the error I get is below.
    # _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist

    # ttk.Button(root2, image=icon, compound='left', text="Quit", command=root2.destroy).pack()

    ttk.Button(root3, text="Quit", command=root3.destroy).pack()

    ttk.Button(root4, text="Quit", command=root4.destroy).pack()

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want images on all buttons. 
I can only get it to work for one button only.

Comment: Maybe a workaround would be to copy/paste the image and name it something different and then reference that copy in your script?

Comment: You have created four entirely separate instances of the Tcl/Tck environment - that's what `Tk()` does, the window you get from it is just a side-effect.  Images, vars, widgets, etc. that are created in one instance are not usable in any other instance.  Use `Tk()` *once*, use `Toplevel()` if you want additional windows.

Comment: I tried making a copy of the image and using that image and it doesn't work either.

Comment: The only way I know of to use different themes for each window is to use a separate Tk() instance for each window. Unless I'm wrong about that.

Comment: If you *must* use multiple instances of `Tk()`, then you have to explicitly create things in the instance that will use them.  `PhotoImage` has a `master=` option to specify this, for example.  Note that this means that you will have to load images multiple times if you want to use them in multiple Tk instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to create another PhotoImage for each window with the `master` keyword:

```py
icon = PhotoImage(master=root, file='test.gif')
icon2 = PhotoImage(master=root2, file='test.gif')
icon3 = PhotoImage(master=root3, file='test.gif')
icon4 = PhotoImage(master=root4, file='test.gif')
```

And then use each icon for the corresponding button:

```py
ttk.Button(root, image=icon, compound='left', text='Quit', command=root.destroy).pack()
ttk.Button(root2, image=icon2, text='Quit', command=root2.destroy).pack()
ttk.Button(root3, image=icon3, text='Quit', command=root3.destroy).pack()
ttk.Button(root4, image=icon4, text='Quit', command=root4.destroy).pack()
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried what you suggested and that doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm sorry that does work, thank you. Is that the only way to do it, seems a bit messy?